# gt table package in R produces header error

Tags: r, quarto, gt

I am using the gt() table package in R and so far I love it. However for some reason when I publish the below in quarto I get an awkward table header that says "?caption" in bold. However when I run the table separately, I don't get anything.

Any thoughts?

Ignore the titles and columns names, I know it doesn't make sense with the diamonds package

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

business_segment_summary <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  summarise(n=n(),
    sum=sum(price),
    sum_od=sum(price,na.rm=TRUE),
    prop_25=quantile(price,.25,na.rm=TRUE),
    prop_50=quantile(price,.5,na.rm=TRUE),
    prop_75=quantile(price,.75,na.rm=TRUE),
    mean=mean(price,na.rm=TRUE),
    mean_aging=mean(table),
    mean_rank=mean(depth),
    prop_od=mean(carat),
    sd=sd(price,na.rm=TRUE),
    mad=mad(price,na.rm=TRUE),
    .groups="drop"
    ) %>% 
  mutate(tar_prop=sum/sum(sum),
         n_prop=n/sum(n))

business_segment_summary %>% 
  select(1,n,tar_prop,n_prop,prop_od,prop_25,prop_50,prop_75) %>% 
  gt::gt()
  gt::cols_label(cut="Business Segment",
                 n="Customer #",
                 tar_prop="% of TAR",
                 n_prop="% of Customers",
                 prop_od=gt::html("% of Customers<br>with overdue"),
                 prop_25="25%",
                 prop_50="50%",
                 prop_75="75%") %>% 
  gt::tab_spanner(label="Customer Account Percentile ($k)",columns = c(prop_25,prop_50,prop_75)) %>% 
  gt::fmt_number(c(prop_25,prop_50,prop_75),decimals = 0,scale_by = 1/1e3) %>% 
  gt::fmt_number(n,decimals = 0) %>% 
  gt::fmt_percent(c(3:5),decimals = 0) %>% 
  gt::opt_stylize(style=1,color="red") %>% 
  gt::tab_header(title="Summary of TAR by business segments") %>% 
  gt::cols_align(align="left",columns = 1)
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to have an example along with a full qmd file? Because if I run the code in a qmd file, it works as intended.

Comment: hi! sure, does it mean to include the yaml headers?

Comment: Yes, a complete minimal example of a qmd file that showcases problem.

Comment: okay, give me 24 hours to respond

Comment: You do not have a pipe between gt::gt() and  gt::cols_label. When I add the pipe in quarto, the table renders with any ?caption in heading